# roll off profile stacking data frames

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df= pd.DataFrame({'date':['2017-12-31','2017-12-31'],'type':['Asset','Liab'],'Amount':[100,-100],'Maturity Date':['2019-01-02','2018-01-01']})

df
```

I am trying to build a roll-off profile by checking if the 'Maturity Date' is greater than a 'date' in the future. I am trying to achieve something like:

```
#First Month
df1=df[df['Maturity Date']>'2018-01-31']
df1['date']='2018-01-31'

#Second Month
df2=df[df['Maturity Date']>'2018-02-28']
df2['date']='2018-02-28'

#third Month
df3=df[df['Maturity Date']>'2018-03-31']
df3['date']='2018-02-31'

#first quarter
qf1=df[df['Maturity Date']>'2018-06-30']
qf1['date']='2018-06-30'


#concatenate
df=pd.concat([df,df1,df2,df3,qf1])


df
```

I was wondering if there is a way to :

Allow an arbitrary long number of dates without repeating code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) for repeat `indices` and assign to new column, last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and sorting by [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
d = '2017-12-31'
df['Maturity Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Maturity Date'])

#generate first month and next quarters
c1 = pd.date_range(d, periods=4, freq='M')
c2 = pd.date_range(c1[-1], periods=2, freq='Q')
#join together
c = c1.union(c2[1:])

#repeat rows be indexing repeated index
df1 = df.loc[np.tile(df.index, len(c))].copy()
#assign column by datetimes
df1['date'] = np.repeat(c, len(df))
#filter by boolean indexing
df1 = df1[df1['Maturity Date'] > df1['date']]
print (df1)
   Amount Maturity Date       date   type
0     100    2019-01-02 2017-12-31  Asset
1    -100    2018-01-01 2017-12-31   Liab
0     100    2019-01-02 2018-01-31  Asset
0     100    2019-01-02 2018-02-28  Asset
0     100    2019-01-02 2018-03-31  Asset
0     100    2019-01-02 2018-06-30  Asset
```

Comment: doesn't work for :import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

df= pd.DataFrame({'date':['2017-12-31','2017-12-31'],'type':['Asset','Liab'],'Amount':[100,-100],'Maturity Date':['2019-01-02','2018-01-01']})
df

Comment: I think I found a small bug in the code snippet you provided. The #assign column by date times should read: df1[date]=np.repeat(c,len(df))

Answer (score 2):

You could use a nifty tool in the Pandas arsenal called
[`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html). It
works similarly to `pd.merge`, except that it matches on "nearest" keys rather
than equal keys. Furthermore, you can tell `pd.merge_asof` to look for nearest
keys in only the backward or forward direction.

---

To make things interesting (and help check that things are working properly), let's add another row to `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2017-12-31', '2017-12-31'],'type':['Asset', 'Asset'],'Amount':[100,200],'Maturity Date':['2019-01-02', '2018-03-15']})
for col in ['date', 'Maturity Date']:
         df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])
df = df.sort_values(by='Maturity Date')
print(df)
#    Amount Maturity Date       date   type
# 1     200    2018-03-15 2017-12-31  Asset
# 0     100    2019-01-02 2017-12-31  Asset
```

Now define some new dates:

```
dates = (pd.date_range('2018-01-31', periods=3, freq='M')
         .union(pd.date_range('2018-01-1', periods=2, freq='Q')))
result = pd.DataFrame({'date': dates})
#         date
# 0 2018-01-31
# 1 2018-02-28
# 2 2018-03-31
# 3 2018-06-30
```

Now we can merge rows, matching nearest `dates` from `result` with `Maturity Date`s from `df`:

```
result = pd.merge_asof(result, df.drop('date', axis=1), 
                       left_on='date', right_on='Maturity Date', direction='forward')
```

In this case we want to "match" `date`s with `Maturity Date`s which are greater
so we use `direction='forward'`.

---

Putting it all together:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2017-12-31', '2017-12-31'],'type':['Asset', 'Asset'],'Amount':[100,200],'Maturity Date':['2019-01-02', '2018-03-15']})
for col in ['date', 'Maturity Date']:
         df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])
df = df.sort_values(by='Maturity Date')

dates = (pd.date_range('2018-01-31', periods=3, freq='M')
         .union(pd.date_range('2018-01-1', periods=2, freq='Q')))
result = pd.DataFrame({'date': dates})
result = pd.merge_asof(result, df.drop('date', axis=1), 
                       left_on='date', right_on='Maturity Date', direction='forward')

result = pd.concat([df, result], axis=0)
result = result.sort_values(by=['Maturity Date', 'date'])
print(result)
```

yields

```
   Amount Maturity Date       date   type
1     200    2018-03-15 2017-12-31  Asset
0     200    2018-03-15 2018-01-31  Asset
1     200    2018-03-15 2018-02-28  Asset
0     100    2019-01-02 2017-12-31  Asset
2     100    2019-01-02 2018-03-31  Asset
3     100    2019-01-02 2018-06-30  Asset
```